# Client not found in kerberos database while initializing kadmin Interface

Tags: security, hadoop, authentication, kerberos, bigdata

When I tried to create Principal (**"prabhat/admin**") in Kerberos (**Kadmind Server**) using the **addprinc** command.

```
kadmin -q "addprinc prabhat/admin"
```

**I got the following error**

*Authenticating as principal prabhat/admin with password.*

*Kadmin: client not found in kerberos database while initializing kadmin interface*

Answer (score 10):

In order to create principals in Kadmin server, first you will have to create a principal using kadmin.local command,

```
kadmin.local -q "addprinc user1/admin"
kadmin.local -q "list_principals"
```

will give a list of principals, that will help you to get authenticated.

Now, you can use user1/admin as an authorized principal to create further principals, without using kadmin.local

```
kadmin -p user1/admin -q "addprinc user2/admin"
```